How an algorithm is implemented in FOL?
According to Gödel's theorem on expressibility, every recursive relation is expressible, every recursive function is representable. I looked at the proof of this theorem, and the proof seems to make sense. However, the intuition for what this theorem seem to imply is still not there, my mind is still trying to see how would a programming language in FOL look like? How would the interpreter work. For example, how would one go about expressing the algorithm for ADD(a,b,c) predicate that returns 0 if c=a+b or 1 otherwise. How would one follow the steps of this algorithm in order to see if $(2+2=4)$ or that $\neg (5+4=10)$?

Several implementations available: Recursive functions, Turing machine, Finite-state machine,... To perform a computation, we can use the method provided by Peano axioms for arithmetic: $2+2=SS(0)+SS(0)=S[SS(0)+S(0)]=SS[SS(0)+0]=SS[SS(0)]=SSSS(0)=4$.

The computation you have provided is not effective though. If a concept like proof template was a thing, then I feel like it would make sense to me. Otherwise, the process seem to require "ingenuity".

If you need a "real" implementation, ask to your pocket calculator: he knows how to do it... Predicate logic is not a programming language, but you can explore the links with computability theory suing some textbook; like George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, Computability and Logic (Cambridge UP, 5th ed. 2007)

See also the post How to prove x=5
using the Peano Axioms?

The key idea is being able to encode sequences of natural numbers as a single natural number. You can directly encode the state of a simple program at any one time as a sequence of natural numbers (variable values and the line number), and then encode a "run" of a program (the sequence of states from start to end of execution). The FOL is then $\exists x$ encoding the run s.t. when you unpack $x$, the state at time $i$ and $i+1$ are related how the program says they should be related. Is this what you're looking for?

@TomKern no, for me the confusion is about the link between provability and computability. The fact that everything that can be computed can be proved in some system of arithemtic. But I like your comment to, about the fact that a Turing machine can be arithmetically encoded.

It seems that understanding mathematics is like having a common cold, without trying you can understand a concept in a week. By trying hard you are going to understand in seven days :)
